# Type Erasure and Object's .equals() Method Returning Unexpected Results in Generic Method

Tags: java, generics

I'm working on learning how generics work in Java, and I'm going through exercises in the Deitel & Deitel "Java - How to Program" book to gain some proficiency in the subject. I'm confused by the results of the following program:

```
/*
*   Exercise 20.7 from "Java - How To Program". This program will implement a 
*   generic isEqualTo() method that calls the equals() method on 
*   the passed in references. I suspect it will only return true if the 
*   passed in references refer to the same object, as the generic param will
*   be replaced with Object after compilation, which means that the equals()
*   method will be that of Object, which compares if two Objects are the SAME
*   object.
*/

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class EqualTo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[] intArray1 = {3, 4, 6, 2};
        Integer[] intArray2 = {5, 0, 7, 1};

        // identical content, but will become different lists, so should be
        // false when compared in isEqualTo to each other
        Float[] floatArray1 = {3.3f, 4.4f, 1.2f};
        Float[] floatArray2 = {3.3f, 4.4f, 1.2f};

        ArrayList<Integer> intList1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(intArray1));
        ArrayList<Integer> intList2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(intArray2));
        ArrayList<Float> floatList1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(floatArray1));
        ArrayList<Float> floatList2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(floatArray2));

        // CONSOLE OUTPUT: false - expected
        System.out.println(isEqualTo(intList1, intList2));
        // CONSOLE OUTPUT: true - expected
        System.out.println(isEqualTo(intList1, intList1));

        // ****CONSOLE OUTPUT: true - unexpected *****
        System.out.println(isEqualTo(floatList1, floatList2));

        // CONSOLE OUTPUT: true - expected
        System.out.println(isEqualTo(floatList1, floatList1));
    }

    public static <T> boolean isEqualTo(ArrayList<T> list1, ArrayList<T> list2) {
        return (list1.equals(list2) ? true : false);
    }
}
```

The exercise states that I should implement isEqualTo() by calling the equals() method as I've done. I would have expected the method to return true only if the passed in list1 and list2 were referring to the SAME object, as the definition of the equals method in Object's API states:

> Taken from :
>   [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-](http://%20Taken%20from%20:%20[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-][1)
>
> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

But, as you can see by my comments, the output when I pass in two DIFFERENT objects that have the same state is true. Here are the relevant portions of the code that is behaving unexpectedly:

```
// identical content, but will become different lists, so should be
// false when compared in isEqualTo to each other
Float[] floatArray1 = {3.3f, 4.4f, 1.2f};
Float[] floatArray2 = {3.3f, 4.4f, 1.2f};

ArrayList<Float> floatList1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(floatArray1));
ArrayList<Float> floatList2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(floatArray2));

// ****CONSOLE OUTPUT: true - unexpected *****
System.out.println(isEqualTo(floatList1, floatList2));
```

How is this so? I thought at compile time, the generic `<T>` type-parameter was changed to its upper bound, which in this case is Object since I don't have any extends or super keywords in here. If that's the case, floatList1 and floatList2 are different objects so they should not be equal according to Object's equals() method correct?

Comment: `isEqualTo` will be erased to `boolean isEqualTo(ArrayList, ArrayList)`, not `boolean isEqualTo(Object, Object)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are correct about `Object`, [`Float.equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) and [`Integer.equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) **override** `Object.equals`; the linked `Float` Javadoc says (in part)

> Note that in most cases, for two instances of class `Float`, `f1` and `f2`, the value of `f1.equals(f2)` is true if and only if
>
> ```
> f1.floatValue() == f2.floatValue()
> ```

While the `Integer` Javadoc says

> Compares this object to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not `null` and is an `Integer` object that contains the same `int` value as this object.

Comment: I understand that Float and Integer override equals(). I'm confused because I thought that at compile-time, the <T> in the generic method was replaced by Object, so any params I pass in become Objects and thus the equals() method of Object is the one being called in the method. Is this not the case?

Comment: `Object` plus an appropriate cast; regardless of the type of reference, the *overloaded* method will be called.

Answer (score 2):

According to Object's equals method, they wouldn't be, but `List` [overrides](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) that `equals` specification:

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements `e1` and `e2` are equal if `(e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)`).) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the `equals` method works properly across different implementations of the `List` interface.

Comment: Technically, `List` specifies the behaviour but it's `AbstractList` that actually overides it.

Comment: @PaulBoddington `List` refines the contract; `AbstractList` implements it.  Fair?

Comment: Yes it is fair. I just wouldn't use the word overrides, but I guess `List` does override the specification.

Comment: @PaulBoddington But since this is a generic method, isn't the type of list1 and list2 Object, and not Float or Integer? I guess that's where I'm confused, I figured at compile-time the generic parameter was changed to Object so it becomes an Object reference throughout the method.

Comment: @Daniel.Schroeder I see what you're saying, but it doesn't work like that. Whether it's a `List<Float>`, a `List<Object>` or a raw `List` doesn't matter. Since `Float` overrides `equals`, it's the version of `equals` in `Float` that's used when you try to compare two lists containing `Floats`.